# How to fix problem with "Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values" in R

Tags: r, plot, error-handling, scatter-plot

I am trying to write a function which will do scatter plotting for me,

the data structure that I am working with looks as follow:

```
'data.frame':   129 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Player      : Factor w/ 129 levels "Abbrederis, Jared",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ College     : Factor w/ 79 levels "Alabama","Arizona",..: 78 20 65 77 27 48 67 31 31 19 ...
 $ Position    : Factor w/ 7 levels "DB","LB","OL",..: 7 7 6 4 4 4 2 2 7 7 ...
 $ OverallGrade: num  5.2 5.96 5.4 5.16 5.45 5.1 6.6 5.37 5.9 6.4 ...
 $ Height      : int  73 73 77 70 68 73 77 73 71 77 ...
 $ ArmLength   : num  31.4 32.6 34 31.2 31 ...
 $ Weight      : int  195 212 265 225 173 218 255 237 198 240 ...
 $ HandLength  : num  9.62 9 9 9.5 8.88 ...
 $ Dash40      : num  4.5 4.56 4.74 4.82 4.26 4.48 4.66 4.64 4.43 4.61 ...
 $ BenchPress  : int  4 14 28 20 20 19 15 22 7 13 ...
 $ VerticalJump: num  30.5 39.5 33 29.5 38 38 34.5 35 38.5 32.5 ...
 $ BroadJump   : int  117 123 118 106 122 121 119 123 122 119 ...
 $ Cone3Drill  : num  6.8 6.82 7.42 7.24 6.86 7.07 6.82 7.24 6.69 7.33 ...
 $ Shuttle20   : num  4.08 4.3 4.3 4.49 4.06 4.46 4.19 4.35 3.94 4.39 ...
 $ Position1   : Factor w/ 7 levels "WO","DB","S",..: 1 1 6 4 4 4 5 5 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scores")= num [1:7(1d)] 4.54 4.75 5.22 4.59 4.58 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "DB" "LB" "OL" "RB" ...
```

I managed to do the plotting without writing a function and the code works:

```
with(nfl,plot(nfl$Dash40,nfl$BenchPress,
              pch=c(1,3,4,2,0,8,5),
              col=c("black","red","blue","darkgreen","purple","orange","gray"),
              xlab = "Bench Press weight", 
              ylab="40-year dash time in seconds"),
              panel.first = grid())
legend("bottomright", legend=levels(nfl$Position), 
       pch=c(1,3,4,2,0,8,5),
       cex=0.5,
       col=c("black","red","blue","darkgreen","purple","orange","gray"))
a<-paste(nfl$Player,nfl$BenchPress)
text(nfl$Dash40,nfl$BenchPress,label=as.character(a),cex=0.5)
```

[image]

So basically I want to see relationship between different numeric variables, and I thought if the code above work, the following function should work as well,

```
myplot<-function(xvar,yvar,xlab,ylab){
  b<-paste("xlab","vs","ylab")
  xvar<-nfl$"xvar"
  yvar<-nfl$"yvar"
  with(nfl,plot(yvar,xvar),
                pch=c(1,3,4,2,0,8,5),
                col=c("black","red","blue","darkgreen","purple","orange","gray"),
                xlab="xlab",ylab="ylab",
                main="b")
}

myplot(Dash40,BenchPress,dash,bench)
```

I used Dash40 and BenchPress to test the function but it turns out the function doesn't work:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) :
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

Essentially I am trying to do the same job using two different codes, why the second one doesn't work? Could someone please give me some hinds on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused by your function. Why does it have arguments `xvar,yvar` that it overwrites without use?

What is meant by `nfl$"xvar"` and `nfl$"yvar"`?

Why is this done at all since you then use `with(nfl,...`?

If nfl doesn't have columns called `xvar` or `yvar` then they will cause an error or be interpreted as `NULL`; if you plot `NULL` then you need to specify the limits of the plot since this cannot be found from the data.

The function fails because you are plotting `NULL`

You also need to pass the data from `nfl` to the function as there is a danger that `Dash40` and `BenchPress` will not be found, since they only exist within nfl. To do the you use the `$` symbol. Instead of `BenchPress` you should pass `nfl$BenchPress` to the function.

The below should work.

```
myplot<-function(xvar,yvar,xlab,ylab){
  b<-paste(xlab,"vs",ylab)
  plot(yvar,xvar,
                pch=c(1,3,4,2,0,8,5),
                col=c("black","red","blue","darkgreen","purple","orange","gray"),
                xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,
                main=b)
}

myplot(nfl$Dash40,nfl$BenchPress,"dash","bench")
```

Comment: VarX is to fill the name of the column ... so is VarY... for example if I have myplot(Dash40,BenchPress...) , the string will replace what’s in the plot(xvar,yvar)

Comment: You seem to surround variables in quotes such as `"xlab"` when trying to use them. This does not work in R, you end up making a string instead.

Comment: Hi, I run the code you suggested, here's the message I received:Error during wrapup: object 'dash' not found

Comment: Sorry, dash and bench should be quoted, since these are strings not objects. I will edit the answer.